# Django comments. How back to page after validation error

Tags: python, django

Below there is my code. I don't know how to redirect back after some validation errors
Urls.py:

```
    (r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
```

views.py:

```
def show_episode(request, episode) :
episode = get_object_or_404(Episode, pk=episode)

return render_to_response('episode.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request, {
    'episode' : episode,
    }))
```

episode.html:

```
        <div class="subsection">
        {% get_comment_form for episode as form %}
        <table>
            <form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form }}
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post">
                        <input type="submit" name="preview" value="Preview">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url episode episode.id %}" />
            </form>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="subsection">{% render_comment_list for episode %}</div>
```

I want to come back to this form when there will be some errors.

---

I try, but I have an error: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute '_meta'
Code:

```
def comments(request) :
if request.method == 'POST' :
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if (form.is_valid()) :
        form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST['next'])
return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it the other way around: process the form in the same view (that is, set `<form action=""`, this way the user won't lose his inputs (as he would with a redirect).

You can still *call* the other view via this view, though. ( `if request.method == 'POST'`)

When there was no Error, send a `response.redirect` to a success view.